# CSS with unknown source

Tags: html, css

[Answered]

the style of the body of the website I made is overwriting color variables I use to implement themes to my website. The problem is that the style is not in my code. I only changed the color values on the `:root{}`, first I thought it might be some caching issue but rebooting my computer doesn't work.

here is an image of my problem, what is weird to me is how some variables are spelled differently:

[I wonder where the CSS in the purple box is coming from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/746m5.png)

here's my relevant code:
css:

```
:root {
        --primary-color: #fff;
        --secondary-color: #f2f2f2;
        --tertiary-color: #333;
        --quaternary-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.2);
        --quinary-color: #000;
        --senary-color: #000;
        --septenary-color: #000;
        --octonary-color: #000;
        --nonary-color: #000;
        --denary-color: #000;
        --highlights: #4CAF50;
        --warnings: #F00;
      }
    
      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
      }
```

html (in php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./includes/main.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          <script src="./includes/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
          <style>
            body{
              background-image: url("BG.png");
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: auto;
              background-attachment: fixed;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        
        <body>
          <div id="navbar">
          </div>
          <div id="sidenav">
          </div>
          <div id="content">
          </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

the file structure looks like the folowing:

```
web[
  includes[
    main.css,
    jquery-3.1.1.min.js
  ],
  index.php,
  BG.png
]
```

^if that makes sense

In the rest of my code no style tag is used to asign CSS, as said I tried rebooting, I got disable cache checked, Incognito doesnt work, commenting the cdnjs.cloudflare.com CSS out also has no effect. If you want any more info please ask.

Thank you very much for taking your time to read this!

Comment: Can you try deactivating your browser extensions and refresh?

Comment: The CSS is on `element.style` — so it could conceivably be added programmatically by some javascript.

Comment: it seems like you are using some kind of framework. You should include that in your question and in the tags of your question

Answer (score 0):

I had this bit of js, which I completely overlooked:

```
<script>
  function setColorTheme() {
    document.body.style.setProperty('--primary-color', "#fff");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--secondary-color', "#f2f2f2");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--tertiary-color', "#333");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--quaternary-color', "#eee");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--quinary-color', "#000");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--senary-color', "#000");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--octonary-color', "#000");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--nonary-color', "#000");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--denary-color', "#000");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--highlights-color', "#4CAF50");
    document.body.style.setProperty('--warnings-color', "#F00");
  }
</script>
```

I am sorry for asking this question, some say there's no such thing as a dumb question, this one proved em wrong.
Thanks to [@Stephen P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) for pointing out it could be added by js.